# JavaScript confirm box with redirect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to ask a user to confirm the delete of his post. I managed it using the confirm function from jQuery but I wanted to create an overlay box with more customization options and after browsing the web I came up with this:

Info: CMS in question is Wordpress

So first the theme: index.php:

```
<li class="EditDel">
    <?php u_delete_post_link('Delete', '', ''); ?>
</li>
```

PHP function:

```
function u_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete This', $before = '', $after = '') {
    global $post;

    $message = "Are you sure you want to delete ".get_the_title($post->ID)." ?";
    $delLink = wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
    $htmllink = "<a href='' onclick = \" u_ask_go('".$message."','".$delLink."' ) \"/>".$link."</a>";
    echo $before . $htmllink . $after;
}
```

Now for the actual problem the link above fires a js function with the message and the link:

```
function u_ask_go(msg,link)
{   
    u_confirm(msg,link, function () {
        window.location.href = arguments[0];
    });
}
```

and the u_confirm function:

```
function u_confirm(message, link, callback) {
    jQuery('#confirm').modal({
        closeHTML: "<a href='#' title='Close' class='modal-close'>x</a>",
        position: ["20%",],
        overlayId: 'confirm-overlay',
        containerId: 'confirm-container', 
        onShow: function (dialog) {
            var modal = this;

            modal.link = link;

            //console.log(modal.link);

            jQuery('.message', dialog.data[0]).append(message);


            // if the user clicks "yes"
            jQuery('.yes', dialog.data[0]).click(function () {
                // call the callback

                if (jQuery.isFunction(callback)) {
                    //console.log(modal.link);
                    callback.apply(modal.link);
                }
                // close the dialog
                modal.close(); // or $.modal.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**Problem1:** The callback function does not fire

**Problem2:** The dialog collapses and the link executes without user pressing anything

**Observation:** Before the modal div is appended the link variable is visible but not in the function on the dialog yes button seems not visible

Hope someone can help

EDIT (HTML buildup):

```
    <!-- modal content -->
    <div id='confirm'>
        <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
        <div class='message'></div>
        <div class='buttons'>
            <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- preload images -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
        <img src='img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
    </div>
```

EDIT2:

```
echo wp_enqueue_script('simplemodal', $blogroot.'/js/jquery.js');
echo wp_enqueue_script('simplemodal', $blogroot.'/js/jquery.simplemodal.js', array("jquery"));
echo wp_enqueue_script('confirmtest', $blogroot.'/js/confirmtest.js', array("jquery"));
```

Comment: No need to preface with "I'm new" ... we're all new , it's OK. Plus we easily see your score there....

Comment: Lots of info, thanks. The big missing piece to this question is the actual markup — when you use Firebug or the Chrome inspector to view the modal, can you "copy as HTML" and paste here? Without this markup, we can't really tell what the JS is operating on and what might be going wrong with it. It's not possible to deduce what the markup might be from this PHP.

Comment: added the html section for the modal content it is hard to copy the buildup from FireBug (see problem2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is not to put your function in an onClick="" attribute, you should use jQuery to call the function like so, and store your variables in custom data attributes (info [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes))

jQuery:

```
$('a#confirmDelete').live('click', function(e) {

    // Prevent default
    e.preventDefault();

    var msg = $(this).attr('data-message');
    var link = $(this).attr('data-del-link');

    u_confirm(msg,link, function () {
        window.location.href = arguments[0];
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
function u_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete This', $before = '', $after = '') {
    global $post;

    $message = "Are you sure you want to delete ".get_the_title($post->ID)." ?";
    $delLink = wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
    $htmllink = "<a href="#" id="confirmDelete" data-message="' . $message . '" data-del-link="' . $delLink . '" />".$link."</a>";
    echo $before . $htmllink . $after;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Coulton for the reply. Seems to be going in the right directon but now I get the error in FireBug when executing saying: jQuery("#confirm").modal is not a function Witch is in the u_confirm functon: Line: jQuery('#confirm').modal( Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe this info could help solve my problem: I added scripts by adding this lines into my functions.php file(see EDIT2 in the post). The problem is that when looking trough firebug I see that jq and confirmtest load correcty but dosent whant to load jquery.simplemodal.js

Comment: Added the scripts into the header.php file instead of functions and now seems everything loaded looking at firebug but still get the same error. Any Idea what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it to work Thanks again to Coulton to point me in the right direction.
But just for the meaning of completing the answer:

1. I had to include the scripts the right way in the functions.php file not the header(**note:** the first parameter needs to differ for every script thats why it didnt load correcty in the first place):

   echo wp_enqueue_script('jquery', $blogroot.'/js/jquery.js');
   echo wp_enqueue_script('simplemodal', $blogroot.'/js/jquery.simplemodal.js', array("jquery"));
   echo wp_enqueue_script('confirmtest', $blogroot.'/js/confirmtest.js', array("jquery"));
2. In my case the following 2 lines didn't work:

   var msg = $(this).attr('data-message');

   var link = $(this).attr('data-del-link');

Had to replace them with this:

```
var msg = jQuery(this).attr('data-message');
var link = jQuery(this).attr('data-del-link');
```